# "Cannot find the X.509 certificate" on Production WCF but works in Staging and local

Tags: wcf, ssl

We have a Certificate provided to us by a company we are integrating with.  The Certificate needs to be installed under "Current User\Trusted People" (to work with their SDK).

Our WCF service is running under IIS and the Application Pool Identity is assigned to a specific user.

On my local machine, everything works fine.
On our Staging server, I logged in as the user that the WCF service runs as and installed the Certificate, and everything runs fine.
On our Production server, I did the same thing, and it doesn't find the Certificate.
The Certificate is definitely there.  I see it there when logged in as that user.  I can use "Find Certificates" from the root of "Current User" and it is found, but when my code runs, it can't find the Certificate.

Another strange piece of the puzzle is that if I log into the Production server as the user that runs the Application Pool in IIS, the code runs fine (it has no trouble finding the certificate).  It's only when the code is run via the actual Service in IIS that it has trouble finding the certificate.

Every question I see about this issue, I have already tried the solutions (or they don't apply).
Can anyone tell me any things to go look at to see why this setup works in Staging but not in our Production server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the "LoadUserProfile" setting in the "Advanced Settings" of the Application Pool inside IIS.  Setting it to "True" loaded the Certificates.
I discovered this on accident after running a Command Prompt as the user who runs the Service in IIS.  When that Command Prompt was open, the code suddenly was able to find the Certificates correctly.